# how to add probabilities to the game?

Tags: c++, probability

This program runs great, but like a true casino owner. I want the payout to be as minimal as possible without adding more possibilities. The way I want to do that is to add probabilities to each number. there 8 possibilities (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) I want 7 to occur the least. So I want to set probabilities as 2-6 at 75% (that's 15% each) 8-9 at 20% (that's 10% each) and 7 at 5%. Can someone help me?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int Random(int low, int high);
int Result(int a, int b, int c, int chips, int bet);
int main()
{
  srand( time(0) );
  int low1(2), low2(2), low3(2);
  int high1(9), high2(9), high3(9);
  int menu=0;
  int bet =0;
  bool quit=0;
  cout << "Player's chips: $1000" << endl;
  int chips=1000;
  while (!quit)
  {
     cout << "1) Play slot. 2) Exit.";
     cin >> menu;
     switch (menu)
     {
        case 1:
        {
           cout << "Enter your bet: ";
           cin >> bet;
           if (bet<=0 || bet>chips)
           {
              cout << "You did not enter a valid bet." << endl;
              menu=1;
           }
           else
           {
              int a = Random(low1,high1);
              int b = Random(low2,high2);
              int c = Random(low3,high3);
              cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
              chips = Result(a,b,c,chips,bet);
              cout << "Player's chips: $" << Result(a,b,c,chips,bet) << endl;
           }
           break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
             cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
             quit=1;
             break;
        }
        default:
        {
        cout << "Not a valid menu !"<<endl;
        }
     }
   }
     if (chips <=0)
     {
         cout << "You have $0 ! Game Over !" << endl;
         quit=1;
     }
}

 int Random(int low, int high)
 {
    int random;
    random = low + rand() % ((high+1)-low);
    return random;
 }

  int Result(int a, int b, int c, int chips, int bet)
  {
     if ((a==7 && b==7 && c==7))
     {
       cout << "You won 10 times your bet !($" << (bet*10) << ")" << endl;
       chips=chips+(bet*10);
     }
     if ((a==b==c) && !(a==7 && b==7 && c==7))
     {
        cout << "You won 5 times your bet !($" << (bet*5) << ")" << endl;
        chips=chips+(bet*5);
     }
      if ((a==b || a==c || b==c) && !(a==b==c) && !(a==7 && b==7 && c==7))
     {
      chips=chips+(bet*3);
      cout << "You won 3 times your bet ! ($" << (bet*3) << ")" << endl;
      }
    else 
    {
      cout << "You lost your bet ! ($-" << bet << ")" << endl;
      chips=chips-bet;
    }
     return chips;
 }
```

Comment: `(a==b==c)` doesn't do what you think it does. You're mistaking C++ for Python.

Comment: If you know the possibilities you want and their range, why not just generate a number between 1-100, hand that random value to a function that maps it to a result, and store/use that result as appropriate?

Comment: you're right, rightfold. I'll change that

Comment: Btw true casino owner does not want payout to be as minimal as possible. There are regulations...

Comment: @StarPilot I don't know why I didn't think of that. Okay, I got this figured out now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an array of values [0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.4, 0.55, 0.7, 0.85] corresponding to values 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5. 6 is if a generated random number > 0.85.

Then get a random number r from 0 to 1.

```
if r <=0.05 then it is 7
else if r <= 0.15 then it is 8
else if r <= 0.1 then it is 9
...
else if r <= 0.85 then it is 5
else it is 6
```

You can figure out how to write it down as a loop if you want.

Comment: or using `std::lower_bound` instead of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write the function as follows (it could be reworked into something better, but it is a start that should work):

```
// Generate a random number 2-9, with weighted probabilities
int Random()
{
   int number; // number 1-9 to generate
   int prob; // probability

   // Generate probability value 0-99
   prob = rand() % 100;

   // Calculate number with desired probability "additive"
   if (prob < 15) // 15% probability for 2
     number = 2;
   else if (prob < 30) // 15% probability for 3
     number = 3;
   else if (prob < 45) // 15% probability for 4
     number = 4;
   else if (prob < 60) // 15% probability for 5
     number = 5;
   else if (prob < 75) // 15% probability for 6
     number = 6;
   else if (prob < 80) // 5% probability for 7
     number = 7;
   else if (prob < 90) // 10% probability for 8
     number = 8;
   else                // 10% probability for 9
     number = 9;
   return number;
}
```

Don't forget to add the following code to seed the random number generator:

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

I hope this isn't for a real slot machine by the way, there could be legal issues if it were :-)